# Excel Equation to keep track of how much time has passed since an event has happened

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say in Column A I have a list of 50 events, each event is in its own row.  In each adjacent cell in column B I'd like to the number of days since that activity was performed.  The rest of the columns would be used to keep track of which dates each activity had been performed on (perhaps Columns C on each have a date on the first row increasing by one day each time and whether or not a given activity had been performed on that date could be marked by an X in that column and row).  Does anyone know of an or method by which this could be performed?  Thank you very much in advance.  Example as of 1/20/18:

```
        Days Since     1/17/18    1/18/18     1/19/18     1/20/18
Event A    2                         X                                
Event B    1                                      X                            
Event C    0                                                 X
Event D    3              X
```

What equation could you use in the "date since column above to make this idea work?

Comment: What's your exact question? Some example would also be great

Comment: I just updated the question to make it more exact!

Comment: You need some base date to measure the days from

Comment: You mean instead of marking an X I would need to just put the date into, say Column C

Comment: What is the input and what is the output? Do you have the dates and you want the "days since" value, or vice versa?

Comment: The dates will be the input, and they will be updated as the events happen. But I'd also like a log that keeps track of when and how often each event happens rather than just the last time it happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this formula in every cell of column B:

```
=TODAY()-INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A2),COUNTA(C2:Z2)+2))
```

**Explanation:**

- `COUNTA` returns the number of non-empty cells in the range (assuming `Z` is your last column).
- `ADDRESS` returns the address of the cell in the given row and column.
- `INDIRECT` returns the value of cell within the given address.
- `TODAY` is self-explanatory ;)
- Subtraction of dates equals the number of days between them.

**Example** (true for today):

```
Column A           Column B            Column C      Column D    ...
          Days since event occurred
Event A               0               17/01/2018    20/01/2018
Event B               2               18/01/2018
```